# JWT token parsing failed [31204], how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jwt, client, twilio

When I execute `Twilio.Device(token)` I'm getting an error:  `{code: 31204, message: "JWT token parsing failed"}`.

This service (https://jwt.io/#debugger-io) is able to decode this tokens, but my js-client is not. In addition, I know that this tokens can be parsed by SDKs for iOS & Android, so I'm intresting what's wrong with my js-app?

I can share the results of #debugger-io's parsing:

```
[header]{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "cty": "twilio-fpa;v=1",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

[payload]{
  "exp": 1553784490,
  "grants": {
    "identity": "24e7e8b3-bb57-5c6e-8f38-9964e6d4edf7",
    "video": {
      "room": "d45373f6-5c78-5d8f-997f-c6f070be940d"
    }
  },
  "iat": 1553780890,
  "iss": "// some string here",
  "jti": "// some string here",
  "sub": "// some string here"
}
```

I've already tried to execute Twilio.Device from token that was getting from quick-start-app, and it works fine. Also I'd been using quick-start-app with my token and it was also broken by this error.

The code below is a way how I'm getting token on client:

```
class CallService{
   constructor(private authService: AuthService, private requestService: RequestService){}

   public getCallToken$(callId: string): Observable<{token: string}>{
    return this.requestService.post('here is our service-url',{
        roomName: callId,
        userName: this.authService.user.uuid
      }
    ).pipe(catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.warn(err);
      alert(`Can't use calls with those parameters: { roomName: ${callId}, userName: ${this.authService.user.uuid} }`);
      return confirm('Try it again?') ? this.getCallToken$(callId) : throwError(err)
    }))
  }

   public createDevice(token: string): Twilio.Device{
      console.log(token);
      return new Twilio.Device(token, {debug: true})
   }
}


// this code with injected CallService
this.callService.getCallToken$('//random-id').subscribe(
   {token} => {
      const device = this.callService.createDevice(token);
      device.on('error', err => console.warn(err));
      device.on('ready', d => { // ... })
      // ... other manipulations 
   }
)
```

I asked my backend developers whether they transform tokens from twilio-api, and they said 'no'.

Comment: is this done in **code**? I mean it must be, because you did tag `javascript` I just don't see any in the question

Comment: @JaromandaX, yea, it's an angular app, but I have a problem with exucuting of this: ```Twilio.Device(token)```, so this's so small. I specified this tag cause Twilio has many libs for any languages.

Comment: ahh, ok ... so you really need a twilio expert (count me out) good luck

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to generate and also request the token? Thanks!

Comment: @philnash , I can't share the code with token-generation, cause I'm frontend-developer :} , but I've edited my question according to explaining of how I'm getting token. I'm almost sure that tokens are correct, cause they work fine with  SDKs for iOS & android on the same app.

Comment: @philnash, also you can check the result of #debugger-io's parsing [located in first code-part of my question]. I suppose the ability to parse a token using this service confirms that the token is valid

Comment: When you request the token, do you get a plain string back? The Twilio examples tend to wrap it in a JSON response and I'm wondering whether your service is doing that too? In your code you pass the result of the request to get the token directly to the device initialiser and I wonder whether you need to extract the token from the result?

Comment: @philnash, no, i'm getting json from the service and angular converts it to object: ```{token: 'base64-string-example'}```. So the service is doing that too. I've updated my code-example.

Comment: Ah, I see, you destructure the token out of the result. Hmm... I recall that there may be limitations on the format of identities. Could you try with an identity that doesn't have hyphens in? I'm going to check this with the team, but that's all I can think of right now.

Comment: Oops! I'm glad you discovered the issue though! Good luck building the rest of the application!

Comment: @ВладВолков I am getting the same error. What was the issue in it. How did you resolve it?

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya there are many libraries from twilio-team and one of them is intended only for voice-calls, another for video- & voice-communications, etc. In my case I tried to use a diferent version on mobile- & web-apps